# How to wake a sleeping thread from another thread in C# .net?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to wake a sleeping thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3460280/is-there-a-way-to-wake-a-sleeping-thread)

I have a windows forms application in C# .net. I am using namedpipes to communicate with a c++ application. The communication part is running fine.
In the form load event, i start two background threads, one of them is for receving. The receiving thread is in infinite while loop. It sleeps when there is no data to be read and when data arrives, it reads it and then pushes it in a message queue(globally created). i want to use the other that i created when the form loaded to read the message queue and update the UI. what i want is that as soon as the second thread is created, it should go in infinite sleep and when the reading thread has read 4 or more messages, it should generate some sort of signal that wakes up the sleeping thread. then the thread processes the message queue until its empty and then goes to back to sleep until it receives another message from the receiving thread.

Comment: Do *not* sleep at all, get rid of that.  The thread always be calling the pipe stream's Read() method.

Comment: that is what i thought, but i want to process the data received and i dont want to miss any data that comes next. so i want the processing to be done by another thread, that should only wakeup when this thread recevies something.

Answer (score 0):

You should wait on a [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.manualresetevent.aspx) or [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx) instead of sleeping.